# Python , regular expressions, replace text containing a word

Tags: python, regex

I wanna replace all text if it contains a given word ( example : 'mama') . i used the following code:

```
import re 
text1 = 'I love mama so much'
result = re.sub(r"\bmama\b",'Nice', text1)
print (result)
```

The result of this is : 'I love Nice so much', however i want it to be only 'Nice'.

How can i do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the the regex string in wildcards.

```
result = re.sub(r".*\bmama\b.*",'Nice', text1)
```

. stands for any character and * stands for 0+ amount of the character to the left of it.

Comment: Thanks ! but why did u put `result = re.sub(r"\b.*mama.*\b",'Nice', text1)` instead of `result = re.sub(r".*\bmama\b.*",'Nice', text1)`

Comment: I just changed that actually, it was an error on my part.

Comment: however i tried the first expression and it worked also :)

Comment: It would work, the difference being that the first version would catch any instance of 'mama' within words, e.g. 'mamabear', and the second version would only catch singular instances, e.g. 'mama'

Comment: Thanks @Magnetron ...i voted up for your answer , but i guess my votes are not counted since i am new !

Comment: No problem :) You should be able to select the preferred answer as the author.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not specifically looking for a regex solution you can do it like this (I'm assuming if it doesn't contain 'mama' you want to return the original phrase?):

```
result = 'Nice' if 'mama' in text1 else text1
```

Comment: Im looking for  regex !

Answer (score 0):

That's what re.sub does. If you want to replace the whole string (with regex), do

```
text1 = 'I love mama so much'
if re.search(r' mama ', text1):
     text1 = 'Nice'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to be 'Nice',

```
result = 'Nice'
```

If there's extra condition that 'Nice' must be in your expression, add an if statement

```
if 'mama' in text1:
    result = 'Nice';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
import re 
text1 = 'I love mama so much'
result = 'Nice' if re.search(r"\bmama\b", text1) else text1
print(result)
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/1HCeFI)

The `'Nice' if re.search(r"\bmama\b", text1) else text1` line means that if there is a regex match of `mama` as a whole word in `text1`, the `result` should be equal to `Nice`, else, it should be equal to `text1`.

Please mind that `re.search` searches for a match anywhere inside a string while `re.match` will only look for matches at the start of a string.

Answer (score 0):

It is base case so

you can use this code as follows

```
import re 
text1 = 'I love mama so much'
result = re.sub(r"m..a",'Nice', text1)
print(result)
```

It can help you on base case..!